# PlayFramework: Ajax + Drag n' Drop + File Upload + File object in controller?

Tags: ajax, file-upload, drag-and-drop, playframework

Does anyone know of a way to upload a file via Ajax and using drag n' drop from the desktop that supports PlayFramework's ability to convert file uploads to a File object?

I've tried several different methods, and nothing works correctly.

Comment: I gotta say I hit the end of this issue as well, just when I thought I got the solution when I looked at my uploads folder it were all 0 bytes files... are you using this one? http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Comment: Yeah i've looked at that, didn't have any luck with it either.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's my successful attempt:

**Edit routes file and add**

```
POST    /upload                                 Application.upload
```

Our controller is `Application`, I'll be using it to keep it simple.

**Edit your Application controller class**

```
public static void upload(String qqfile) {


if (request.isNew) {

    FileOutputStream moveTo = null;

    Logger.info("Name of the file %s", qqfile);
    // Another way I used to grab the name of the file
    String filename = request.headers.get("x-file-name").value();

    Logger.info("Absolute on where to send %s", Play.getFile("").getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "uploads" + File.separator);
    try {

        InputStream data = request.body;


        moveTo = new FileOutputStream(new File(Play.getFile("").getAbsolutePath()) + File.separator + "uploads" + File.separator + filename);
        IOUtils.copy(data, moveTo);

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        // catch file exception
        // catch IO Exception later on
        renderJSON("{success: false}");
    }

}


renderJSON("{success: true}");
}
```

**Edit your Application.html in app/views/Application folder/package**

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
#{set title:'Multiple Uploads' /}

<div id="file-uploader">
    <noscript>
        <p>Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
        <!-- or put a simple form for upload here -->
    </noscript>

    <script>
        function createUploader(){
            var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
                element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
                action: '/upload',
                debug: true
            });
        }

        // in your app create uploader as soon as the DOM is ready
        // don't wait for the window to load
        window.onload = createUploader;
    </script>    
</div>
```

**Edit your main layout: main.html, located in the app/views folder/package and add this line after jQuery**

```
<script src="@{'/public/javascripts/client/fileuploader.js'}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Final notes**
Remember to download the script from [AJAX Upload Valums](http://valums-file-uploader.github.io/file-uploader/), enjoy!

You can also [grab the source here](http://www.mediafire.com/?vxq7yej7ksq4ypb).

I tested it in different browsers it works for me at least. Credits to Riyad in Play! mailing list who hinted me about the `request.body`

P.S: I'm using the one I posted as a comment before

**Edit** 
The answer with code has been added as directed by T.J. Crowder, I agree :)

Comment: Yes,there is no "queue" system though you have to implement it yourself it just "drop all the files" in and it uploads, (or select them with the browse button)

Comment: you should save it as a snippet, to share with the rest of play developers: http://www.playframework.org/community/snippets

Comment: That's fantastic! But although links to other sites can be useful *adjuncts* to answers, the relevant code (even if there's a quite a lot of it) should be contained *in the answer itself* as well. The content of external sites can change, or move, or disappear entirely. Stack Overflow is meant to be a resource for the OP *now*, and for others with the question in the future. More: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 1):

The simple upload part (not drag&drop just click on "upload a file") is not working with Ie7 & 8 (don't try others ie)

See [getting Java Bad File Descriptor Close Bug while reading multipart/form-data http body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163731/getting-java-bad-file-descriptor-close-bug-while-reading-multipart-form-data-htt)

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure this will qualify as an answer since I'm not a hundred percent sure it will work. But it *should* work :)

If I understand you correctly, you want to drag files from the desktop and drop them in a drop zone somewhere in your browser. This triggers an ajax upload call to a play server.

I've got the second part of that working, using a straight jquery ajax post. The files are received just fine. For the first part, I'd try using the dnd support in html 5 (scroll down to Dragging Files):

http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/dnd/basics/