# Play Framework - Ajax File Upload

Tags: playframework

i'm using the solution posted in: [PlayFramework: Ajax + Drag n' Drop + File Upload + File object in controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867007/playframework-ajax-drag-n-drop-file-upload-file-object-in-controller/4893469#4893469) but unsucefully.
I always get a java.io.IOException - Result too large.

I'm trying upload images size of 1,64MB....2MB.
My controller code is same in the topic mentioned.
Tnks.

```
public static void upload(String qqFile) {

    if (request.isNew) {

        FileOutputStream moveTo = null;


        // Another way I used to grab the name of the file
        String filename = request.headers.get("x-file-name").value();

        try {
            InputStream data = request.body;
            moveTo = new FileOutputStream(new File(Play.getFile("").getAbsolutePath()) + File.separator + "uploads" + File.separator + filename);
            IOUtils.copy(data, moveTo);

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            // catch file exception
            // catch IO Exception later on
            renderJSON("{success: " + ex.toString() + "}");
        }

    }

    renderJSON("{success: true}");
}
```

Comment: Hi Fabio, I have the same issue. Where my client is legacy Delphi application. Did you solve this ?