# Upload folder in production in Play Framework 1.2.4

Tags: playframework, tomcat7, playframework-1.x

I'm having a bit of trouble in how to split my application to execute
a deploy in production.

In more detail:

In the application, there is a part where the user can upload images
of their company (logo) to the website, to be used on dynamically
generated hotsites.

However, every time i'm going to execute the deploy, i lose the folder
in production to my dev.

The application in production run on tomcat7/linux. Is there any way I
can leave this image directory in a folder outside the project?
Something like a virtual host to recognize and run?

As, save the file at the time of upload to this host?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Now I'm able to save imgs in directory outside application.
But how i can map /logos to my attachments folder in tomcat?

Tnks

Answer (score 2):

You can set the path in your application.conf. Just set

```
attachments.path=/some/absoute/path
```

See here for the docs, http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/configuration#attachments

Comment: Tnks for answer.
I'm saving the images based in this topic:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867007/playframework-ajax-drag-n-drop-file-upload-file-object-in-controller/4893469#4893469](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867007/playframework-ajax-drag-n-drop-file-upload-file-object-in-controller/4893469#4893469)

This configuration in conf can be applied for this method?

Tnks again